# Does logarithms conjecture imply Gelfond conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Assume that logarithms conjecture is true: Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be algebraic numbers such that $\log(a_1),\cdots,\log(a_n)$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly independant. Then, $\log(a_1),\cdots,\log(a_n)$ are algebraically independant.

Can one assert that Gelfond conjecture is true:
for $\alpha,\beta$ algebraic numbers, $\alpha\notin\{0,1\}$ and $\beta$ of degree $d$ $(d\ge2$), then the numbers $\alpha^\beta,\cdots,\alpha^{\beta^{d-1}}$ are algebraically independant?

I know Schanuel conjecture implies Gelfond conjecture, but Schanuel conjecture is stronger than logarithms conjecture.
And it is known that Gelfond conjecture is true for $d=3$.